# Could not clean up File History data - Element not found

Tags: windows-10, file-history

I have a File History backup and when I try to clean older copies, it spits out that error. Any idea how to solve it? I tried with cmd too. Also verified File history is running in Services.msc. `sfc /scannow`

In control pannel
[image: GUI Error]

In cmd
[image: cmd Error]

sfc /scannow result
[image]

Comment: What Windows version are you on?

Comment: @Saijin_Naib This issue was persistent since I first tried it in 1909 to 20H2 that I am now using.

Comment: Same thing, had it for years on my machine, on each version of Windows I installed. I see it's here on Feedback Hub, maybe add your voice to it: https://aka.ms/AAbxvhn

Comment: @DaviddCeFreitas Will do.

Comment: Looks like is a known bug still not fixed: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/file-history-element-not-found-when-clean-up-old/761eea3d-0ee1-4a4e-a9fd-9bd14546a175

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this a year on, I've searched a lot for a nice answer to this to no avail. My suggestion is the following:

1. Replace the back-up drive with a new, blank one, and use that for storing file history instead.
2. If you ever need to restore from a back-up, you can still access file history on the older drive if needed - just switch the drives again.
3. Once you have enough file history on the new drive, format the old one.
4. If you have the problem on the new drive, switch drives go back to step 1 above.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).